# ImportError When Attempting to Use VMD After Installation

Tags: python-3.x, vmd

I recently attempted to use the Variational Mode Decomposition (VMD) package in Python. After successfully installing the package with the command pip install vmd, I tried to import it into my project using from vmd import VMD.

Unfortunately, this led to the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'VMD' from 'vmd'
I am seeking guidance on how to properly import and use the VMD package in my Python script, as the current import statement is leading to errors.

Here's the code I am using:

from vmd import VMD
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't it from vmdpy import VMD ?